# Is a "separable" algebra over a field finite-dimensional?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, separable-algebras

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a unital associative (possibly non-commutative) $k$-algebra, and let $A^e$ denote the enveloping algebra of $A$, namely, $A^e = A \otimes_k A^{op}$.

It seems that there are two typical definitions for separable $k$-algebras. Consider the following two conditions.

1. $A$ is projective as an $A^e$-module.
2. For any field extension $K$ of $k$, the algebra $A \otimes_k K$ is semisimple.

Also consider the following condition.

3. $A$ is **finite-dimensional** over $k$ and the condition 2 is satisfied.

In some literature (e.g. Corollary 10.6 in Pierce's Associative Algebra), it is shown that *1 is equivalent to 3*.

I wonder whether 2 is actually equivalent to 1 and 3, that is,

> **Question:** *Suppose that the condition 2 is satisfied. Then is $A$ finite-dimensional over $k$?*

I found some people say that this question is true, and even adopt the condition 2 as the definition of separable algebras:
e.g. [nLab's article on separable algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separable+algebra), and Lemma 3.3 in Reyes-Rogalski's [*Graded twisted Calabi-Yau algebras are generalized Artin-Schelter regular*](https://doi.org/10.1017/nmj.2020.32). I looked up some cited references, but it seems that in the proofs, $A$ is assumed to be finite-dimensional.

I'm not sure whether the question is true even when $A$ is commutative, or $A$ is a filed.

Comment: What is the enveloping algebra? I only know this term in the context of Lie algebras.

Comment: $A^e$ is the tensor product algebra $A \otimes_k A^{op}$ of $A$ and the opposite algebra $A^{op}$.

Comment: What definition of semisimple are you using? I know a few different ones, but it's possible that they're only equivalent when you already assume finite-dimensionality.

Comment: If you take the product of all matrix algebras $\mathrm{Mat}_n(k)$. Would that be semisimple in your definition?

Comment: @ R. van Dobben de Bruyn A ring is semisimple if it is a semisimple module as a left (or equivalently right) A-module, and a semisimple algebra is just a $k$-algebra which is semisimple as a ring.

Comment: @Echo If you mean we take product for all $n$, then it is not semisimple since a semisimple ring must be artinian and noetherian, and the infinite product of non-zero rings is neither artinian nor noetherian.

Answer (score 7):

I claim that no infinite dimensional algebra $A$ over $k$ satisfies 2.  I am indebted to the comment of @UriyaFirst for the idea of the main step in the proof.

First I claim we may assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.  Indeed, if $[A:k]=\infty$ and satisfies 2, then for an algebraic closure $\overline k$ of $k$ we have that $A'=A\otimes_k \overline k$ is infinite dimensional over $\overline k$ and satisfies 2 over $\overline k$ by transitivity of extension of scalars.

So assume $k$ is algebraically closed and $[A:k]=\infty$.  We show that $A$ does not satisfy $2$.  If $A$ is not semisimple, then it fails 2, so we may assume that $A$ is a direct product of matrix algebras over division algebras and at least one of these division algebras $D$ is infinite dimensional over $k$.  Since extension of scalars commutes with direct product and matrix algebras, it suffices to show that $D\otimes_k K$ is not semisimple for some field extension  $K/k$.

The key observation is that if $F/k$ is an infinite extension, then $F\otimes_k F$ is either not Artinian or not Noetherian.  If $F/k$ is not finitely generated, then $F\otimes_k F$ is not Noetherian by Theorem 11 of P. Vámos, On the minimal prime ideals of a tensor product of two fields, Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 84 (1978), pp. 25-35.  If $F/k$ is finitely generated but infinite dimensional then it has positive transcendence degree. The Krull dimension of $F\otimes_k F$ is the transcendence degree of $F/k$, by Rodney Y. Sharp, The Dimension of the Tensor Product of Two Field Extensions, Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society 9 Issue 1 (1977) pp 42–48.  Thus $F\otimes_k F$ is not Artinian in this case.

There are two cases.  If $[Z(D):k]=\infty$, then $D\otimes_k Z(D)$ has center $Z(D)\otimes_k Z(D)$ by general facts on centers of tensor products over a field, and so the center of $D\otimes_k Z(D)$ is not a finite direct product of fields by the above observation (since it fails either the Artinian or Noetherian condition).  But the center of a semisimple ring is a direct product of fields by Wedderburn-Artin, contradiction.

So assume $[Z(D):k]<\infty$.  Then $Z(D)=k$ because $k$ is algebraically closed. Let $\alpha\in D\setminus k$.  Then $\alpha$ is transcendental over $Z(D)=k$ and so $k\leq K=k(\alpha)$ with $K/k$ a purely transcendental extension.  Now using @UriyaFirst comment (but with a descending chain argument), we have that $K\otimes_k K$ is not Artinian by the above and so has an strictly descending chain of ideals $I_1\supsetneq I_2\supsetneq \cdots$.  Now $D\otimes_k K$ is a free right $K\otimes_k K$-module (since $D$ is a free $K$-module) and so the $(D\otimes_k K) I_k$ form a strictly descending chain of left ideals in $D\otimes_k K$. Thus $D\otimes_k K$ is not left Artinian and hence not semisimple.

Comment: In a previous version of your answer you said that if $D$ is infinite-dimensional over $Z(D)$, then there is a subfield $F$ of $D$ of infinite dimension over $k$. The ring $D$ is a free right $F$-module. Consequently, $D\otimes_kF$ is a free right $F\otimes_kF$-module. The latter ring is not noetherian, so there is a chain of ideals $I_1\subsetneq I_2 \subsetneq I_3\subsetneq\dots$ in $F\otimes_kF$. Since $D\otimes_kF$ is free over $F\otimes_kF$, we get a strictly increasing chain of left ideals $(D\otimes_k F)I_1\subsetneq(D\otimes_k F)I_2\subsetneq\dots$, so $D\otimes_k F$ is not noetherian.

Comment: @Uriya First, The previous version was slightly wrong. What I really get are subfields of unbounded dimension.  I guess they could still all be finite.  It is an open question I believe whether a division algebra all of whose elements are algebraic over its center is necessarily finite dimensional over the center.

Comment: @UriyaFirst, I found what I think is a correct proof now using your idea.

Comment: For the commutative case there is an easier proof.  If $A$ is commutative and satisfies 2., then $A$ is a direct product of fields and so $A\otimes_k A$ will be semisimple since tensor products commute with direct product.  Thus $A$ is a projective $A\otimes_k A$-module and so $A$ satisfies 1 and hence 3.

Comment: The proof is now correct as far as I can tell. Going to the algebraic closure at first indeed bypasses the complications arising if $D$ is algebraic over $k$.

Comment: @UriyaFirst,  yes that fixed the D algebraic over k issue but your comment removed my other obstacle which was more serious.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have a question on the part when you use Vamos's paper. You claim that if $F/k$ is an infinite extension, then $F \otimes_k F$ is not noetherian. I check the paper and found that $F \otimes_k F$ is noetherian iff $F$ is a finitely generated extension, not a finite extension. Actually, I think that for $F = k(x)$, which is an infinite extension of $k$, $F \otimes_k F$ is noetherian.

Comment: I misread it as finite extension.  But if you have a nonalgebraic extension, then $F\otimes_k F$ is not artinian.  So let me fix.

Comment: @H.E., I think I have now fixed the proof.  If $F/k$ is infnitely generated, I can use Vamos.  Otherwise, it is finitely generated and infinite dimensional and so much have positive trancendence degree.  Then $F\otimes_k F$ is not artinian by a result of Sharp and I can use that.